# AWS ALB health check for application server

Tags: amazon-web-services, splunk

What can be a simple ALB health check for 2 app servers behind an ALB. These are not web hence I am not installing http on these servers.

Comment: ALB is an HTTP load balancer.  It's not clear how you will be using it for servers that are "not web."

Answer (score 0):

You have option of configuring HTTP/HTTPS/TCP traffic for health check.

With ALB you need to associate an target group. Health checks are configured against this target group.

Your 2 app servers must be serving some traffic (say: TCP traffic over port 3306, if its running mysql). This is known as traffic port , the same port where your ALB is listening.

When you create Target group, you have to mention that health check will be done on this traffic port.

**This is what you get when you attempt to create target group:**
[image]